# Convert vbscript snippets to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

We have a bunch of vbscript snippets that are stored in a database. They are created by our users and are used during some complex calculations.

We are using the microsoft scriptcontrol to execute them. As we are switching to 64bit applications  we cannot use the scriptcontrol anymore and therefore we are going to start using CodeDom and vb.net instead.

The problem is that we still need to support all those legacy vbscripts until they have been converted to vb.net scripts.

The scripts only contain simple functions taking arbitary number of parameters and do some caluclations on them. As I'm a C# developer I do not have that much experience with vbscript contra vb.net syntax.

Is it easy to convert vbscript code to vb.net (using regex or similar)? Got any pointers or things that I should think of? Or should I just wait until all scripts have been converted by the users (may take a while)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Option Explicit Off` in VB.Net, quite a lot of vbscript code will be ok, but one problem you'd have is that in VB.Net you can't just execute a script by itself, so even if the code might work without any conversion you might not be able to run them in the same way since you'll need to compile them into executables before you can run them. If each script can be executed indepentenly of each other, then you'll either need to compile one executable per script, or have one *master* executable with a big `Select Case` in there to call the relevant code depending on command line parameters.

I'd suggest that it might be worth waiting for the users to convert them though and also keeping  `Option Explicit On` and letting the users go through the scripts and add datatypes and similar, since it's quite possible that might find quite a few bugs in your scripts.

Comment: I don't need a executable. It's possible to compile code at runtime using codedom and that's what I intend to do. As for the code, it will be wrapped into classes. Thanks for the other pointers. Guess I'll just have to try :)